# Two finger scroll stops working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse, suspend, mouse-scroll

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have activated two finger scroll. It works fine but stops working after i suspend my pc. I am using a lenovo T440. My mouse settings are as follows. [image]

Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: I have some issue on ubuntu 18.04 with the two finger scroll especially after supsend.
What I do (but its not a solution) is to reload the kernel module by doing `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` followed by `sudo modprobe psmouse` on a terminal. Not that after the first command the whole touchpad will stop to work, before you reload the module.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer from Manjaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/fixing-multitouch-touchpad-issues-after-resuming-from-suspend-on-thinkpad-t440s-and-others-4-14-4-18/58137) suggests adding the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse_serio2_setup.conf`:

```
options psmouse synaptics_intertouch=0
```

This apparently forces the trackpad to use PS/2 emulation and makes everything all better.  I haven't tested it extensively, but it seems to work in my T450s with Ubuntu 18.04.